# Custom UITableViewCell content not moving when scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a `UITableView` with a custom cell using Storyboards. All the objects inside the custom cell work but when I scroll in my `UITableView` the objects do not move:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCell";

MainCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MainCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.subtitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theEvent.startDate];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
```

[image]

Any ideas on what I have done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code for the UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: The screen shot is for when you scroll or even when the tableview is loaded the contents are beyond the cell height?

Comment: what do you mean by, "the objects don't move"? how many cells do you have? do you have enough such that the table view needs to scroll to see more? If so, then do the cells scroll? what is happening to the actual content?

Comment: The screenshot is when the UITableView is scrolling. The UITableView scrolls but the content in the cells don't move with the cells.

Comment: I think the issue is with your custom cell xib

Comment: Is 'subtitle' a property you have added to MainCell?

Comment: Please post the code for the `MainCell` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The objects that I had placed on the `UITableViewCell` were not actually inside the cell but on top of the `UITableView` and therefore they were acting as "floating" objects.